# OpenLayers snap to road

Tags: javascript, openlayers

i have some marker on my map, and i am trying to draw line between the marker but i want it follow the road ,when i used Google map i follow this example...

http://people.missouristate.edu/chadkillingsworth/mapsexamples/snaptoroad.htm

and got this...

```
if (shiftPressed || path.getLength() === 0) {
          path.push(lineCoordinates[x]);
          if(path.getLength() === 1) {
            poly.setPath(path);
          }
        } else {
          service.route({ origin: path.getAt(path.getLength() - 1), destination: lineCoordinates[x], travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING }, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              for(var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      x++;
```

is there anyway to do the same in OpenLayers?

Comment: If you're just displaying regular tiles then OpenLayers doesn't know anything about the roads.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the feature (road) as an object in a VectorLayer (for example you get it as a WFS), it is possible to snap your line to the road. (You slightly move the vertex of the drawn feature/line according to the distance of the line/feature representing the road). But it is not an easy operation in openLayers, you could just "turn on"...